# Editing xml file with c#

Tags: c#, xml-parsing

I have the following xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfParams xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Params Key="Domain" Value="User123">
    <Variable>
      <Name>Domain</Name>
      <Type>String</Type>
      <Value>User123</Value>
    </Variable>
  </Params>
  <Params Key="Password" Value="Password123">
    <Variable>
      <Name>Password</Name>
      <Type>String</Type>
      <Value>Password123</Value>
    </Variable>
  </Params>
  <Params Key="Username" Value="Domain123">
    <Variable>
      <Name>Username</Name>
      <Type>String</Type>
      <Value>Domain123</Value>
    </Variable>
  </Params>
</ArrayOfParams>
```

I would like to change the password from `Password123` to `NewPassword123`
The xml should be changed in 2 places:

```
<Params Key="Password" Value="Password123">
```

and

```
<Value>Password123</Value>
```

How can this be done?

**EDIT** the XML already exist, not my design. i just need to change it

I tried to use XDocument, but am having problems with the query.
can you provide a linq that knows how to query it?

Comment: What do you mean? Why have you designed the XML file to have redundancy like this? It seems like a bad idea to me. What's generating this file? (I wouldn't expect XmlSerializer to do this...)

Comment: Okay, so it's not actually about serialization and deserialization at all (contrary to your title) - it's just about editing an XML file? What have you tried?

Comment: Have you tried using the XpathNavigator to find the node and edit it?

Comment: Just use one of the many XML parsing possibilities provided in c#: XPathNavigator, XDocument, XmlDocument, etc. What have you tried?

Comment: I tried to user XDocument but i have issues with the query. can you share a code that knows how to parse it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using LINQ to XML?

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);

var passwordParams = doc.Root.Elements("Params").SingleOrDefault(e => (string)e.Attribute("Key") == "Password");

if(passwordParams != null)
{
    passwordParams.Attribute("Value").Value = newPasswordString;
    passwordParams.Element("Variable").Element("Value").Value = ewPasswordString;
}
```

After that you can save the document wherever you want.

I can't test it right now, but general idea should be clear.

Answer (score 0):

This would be one way to do it - using the "older" style `XmlDocument` class which loads the entire XML into memory and allows you to "navigate" around its structure. Works fine if your XML isn't too big (like here).

```
// create XML document and load contents from file
XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
xdoc.Load(@"D:\temp\test.xml");   // adapt this to your own path!

// get the <Params> node with the Key=Password attribute
XmlNode paramsNode = xdoc.SelectSingleNode("/ArrayOfParams/Params[@Key='Password']");

if (paramsNode != null)
{
    // set the value of the "Value" attribute to the new password
    paramsNode.Attributes["Value"].Value = "NewPassword123";

    // get the "Variable/Value" subnode under that <Params> node
    XmlNode valueSubnode = paramsNode.SelectSingleNode("Variable/Value");

    if (valueSubnode != null)
    {
       valueSubnode.InnerText = "NewPassword123";

       // save XmlDocument back out to a new file name
       xdoc.Save(@"D:\temp\modified.xml");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is quite easy with System.Xml.XmlDocument:

```
XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
xmlDocument.LoadXml(source);
XmlNode password = xmlDocument.SelectSingleNode("//Params[@Key='Password']");
password.Attributes["Value"] = "NewPassword123";
XmlNode value = password.SelectSingleNode("./Value");
value.InnerXml = "NewPassword123";
string source = xmlDocument.OuterXml;
xmlDocument.Save(destPath);
```

Hope this helps you.